# Left join and case clause LINQ in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, entity-framework

I am needing to make a left join and also use the select operator case. 
My LINQ basic is this and works:

```
resultado.Dados =
    (
        from a in db.AgendaHorario
        join b in db.Agenda on a.AgendaID equals b.AgendaID
        join c in db.Profissional on a.ProfissionalID equals c.ProfissionalID into d
        from e in d.DefaultIfEmpty()                        
        select new
        {
            id = a.AgendaHorarioID,
            Medico = e.Identificacao     
        });
```

But I must add a new field and it should be formatted, then my LINQ looked like this:

```
resultado.Dados =
  (
    from a in db.AgendaHorario
    join b in db.Agenda on a.AgendaID equals b.AgendaID
    join c in db.Profissional on a.ProfissionalID equals c.ProfissionalID into d
    from e in d.DefaultIfEmpty()                        
    select new
    {
        id = a.AgendaHorarioID,
        Medico = e.Identificacao,
        start = a.Horario.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")            
    }
  );
```

This error happens:

```
LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.
```

If you add the ToList() or AsEnumerable() in `db.AgendaHorario.ToList()` and `db.Agenda.ToList()` and `db.Profissional.ToList()` error that appears is:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

What should I do to have a left join with case and fields and formatted fields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
resultado.Dados =
(
    from a in db.AgendaHorario
    join b in db.Agenda on a.AgendaID equals b.AgendaID
    join c in db.Profissional on a.ProfissionalID equals c.ProfissionalID into d
    from e in d.DefaultIfEmpty()                        
    select new
    {
        id = a.AgendaHorarioID,
        Medico = e.Identificacao,
        start = a.Horario
    }).AsEnumerable().Select(x => new
    {
        id = x.id,
        Medico = x.Medico,
        start = x.start.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")            
    }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

try to set the string in a variable then assign it to your query like this:

> ```
> var myValue = Horario.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
>
> resultado.Dados =   (
> from a in db.AgendaHorario
> join b in db.Agenda on a.AgendaID equals b.AgendaID
> join c in db.Profissional on a.ProfissionalID equals c.ProfissionalID into d
> from e in d.DefaultIfEmpty()                        
> select new
> {
>     id = a.AgendaHorarioID,
>     Medico = e.Identificacao,
>     start = myValue             
> }   );
> ```

Comment: Sorry I did not understand. The code you passed does not work.

Comment: the first line of the code above needs to be supplied by your db.AgendaHorario so you need to modify that line to get your value